# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after updating .htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm getting an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error on my website. I have set up a `.htaccess` file on my Apache server containing the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This is cobbled together from two sources: [Ember.js' routing tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/tutorial/deploying/#toc_apache) and a [guide to forcing HTTPS](https://www.taniarascia.com/redirect-all-http-requests-to-https/).

There must be some kind of redirect loop somewhere here, but  I am unable to determine where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I was able to get it working using the following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! It seems like the difference here is using `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https`.